# Parse json data using service

Tags: android, json, service

I am trying to get the number of rows in database from a webpage which is in json format via a service. Why does my code not allow me to do that?

my service :

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = NotificationService.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String UPDATE_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/webservice/updatecheck.php";
private static final String TAG_ROWCOUNT = "rowcount";
int count;
UpdaterJson jsonUpdater = new UpdaterJson();
JSONObject json = jsonUpdater.getJSONFromUrl(UPDATE_URL);

@Override
//bind an activity to a service
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onstartcommand");
    try {
        count = json.getInt(TAG_ROWCOUNT);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "count "+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

My JsonParser :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class UpdaterJson {

final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // make HTTP request
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,     "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

the webpage output :

```
{"rowcount":2}
```

Logcat says unable to instantiate service.

///edited//
Full logcat :

```
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.NotificationService: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2561)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.UpdaterJson.getJSONFromUrl(UpdaterJson.java:35)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.NotificationService.<init>(NotificationService.java:19)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2558)
03-23 20:02:07.240: E/AndroidRuntime(7989):     ... 10 more
```

**////Edit after switching to IntentService**

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationService extends IntentService {



    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotificationService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static final String TAG = NotificationService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String UPDATE_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/webservice/updatecheck.php";
    public static final String TAG_ROWCOUNT = "rowcount";
    int count;
    UpdaterJson jsonUpdater = new UpdaterJson();
    JSONObject json = jsonUpdater.getJSONFromUrl(UPDATE_URL);
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandle");
        try {
            count = json.getInt(TAG_ROWCOUNT);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `json.getInt("rowcount");`

Notice that in `{"rowcount":2}` the `2` has no quotes around it and that makes it an `Integer`/`Long` …etc

p.s. You need to post more from the logcat and where you start this service so we can help you

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Please post the logcat here and where/how you start this service

Comment: **"Logcat says unable to instantiate service."** My guess? You're getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` but unless you actually post the logcat output then nobody can say for certain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have posted the full logcat data.

Comment: also, i am starting and stoping the service from the options menu. i intend to do it automatically when i get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your full logcat...

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Basically you can't do anything on the main (UI) thread which is long running and all network operations are considered to be potentially long running and will throw that exception.

Even though an Android `Service` is 'invisible', i.e., it doesn't have a UI, it still runs on the main thread.

Two possible fixes would be either to create a separate `Thread` in your `Service` to do the download or simply use an `IntentService`.

The `IntentService` class extends `Service` but it uses its own worker thread to do what it needs to do and then self-terminates.

See the docs for [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Also see [Extending IntentService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService)

**EDIT:** Move these two lines...

```
UpdaterJson jsonUpdater = new UpdaterJson();
JSONObject json = jsonUpdater.getJSONFromUrl(UPDATE_URL);
```

...inside of the `onHandleIntent(...)` method.

It's not the line...

```
count = json.getInt(TAG_ROWCOUNT);
```

...that's causing the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` - it's when you're actually getting the JSON from the URL.

Comment: IntentService is pretty new to me. Do i put the code related to getting the json in in onhandleIntent or onstartcommand? y is it asking for an intent? i dont have a use for an intent. can u be more specific as to how to use the IntentService class?

Comment: @crushman : I've added another link to my answer. The `IntentService` class is a little different to `Service` because it handles its own worker thread and also self-terminates but it's generally pretty easy to use. The `Intent` doesn't need to be anything specific - just add an 'action' such as `com.mycompany.myapp.DOWNLOAD_JSON` - the `IntentService` code can ignore it if you only want it to do one thing. Yes, the `onHandleIntent(...)` method does the work.

Comment: It seems u were right Squonk, IntentService is actually much easier than service itself, however it did not solve the problem i am having. i am still getting the same error in logcat. i have added my new service to my question so u can see how i changed it around. please have a look.

Comment: Squonk u are most wise!! it worked, i didnt expect it to be somethng so simple. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Move the below two line in onCreate of your service(NotificationService)

```
UpdaterJson jsonUpdater = new UpdaterJson();
JSONObject json = jsonUpdater.getJSONFromUrl(UPDATE_URL);
```